# Can I delete a logical E: drive, which popped up after installing dual boot ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu dual-boot in my PC alongside Windows 10. Before installing, i had shrunk my 1TB hard drive and left 200 GB for Ubuntu installation. The installation went fine, but after booting up Windows, I see in disk management, that a new logical drive had appeared, which i did not create, having 512 MB size...Can i safely delete the new drive?

Comment: Might be EFI or /boot (=Do not delete!!) Check the disk manager.

Comment: What is E:? That is not a name Ubuntu uses. Are you expecting us to understand what "disk management" is? You are asking it from a windows perspective...  Please use gparted and other Linux based tools to explain this. Ubuntu will tell you **exactly** what partitions are used for. Windows does not.

Comment: Sorry I messed up! I am a newbie and didn't really think I would receive replies...so I deleted it as in windows the disk was showing empty...but when I boot my pc now, grub rescue comes up...I think I might have deleted the /boot partition as @pLumo suggested...please help me , how to fix it??? Please...

Comment: Will just reinstalling Ubuntu fix it?

Comment: You don't need to reinstall Ubuntu, just reinstall grub.

Comment: Ok, but actually I am not familiar with the process of reinstalling grub, but I do know how to reinstall Ubuntu....and since it was a fresh install anyway, I don't have any important files....will reinstalling Ubuntu fix it? If it can't, then can you help me with reinstalling grub? Btw, thanks a lot for it help 

Comment: Please reply!!!

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu and it is fixed....thank you guys for helping!!!

Comment: Best now to start creating good backups of both Windows & Ubuntu data. Easy to reinstall Ubuntu, but you need your data & settings from /home so you do not have to totally redo them. http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436006

Comment: Thank you! I will surely give it a try!

Answer (score -1):

Do not delete! It contains grub config files! Deleting will cause grub bootloader to fail to start!

Comment: How should that remove a windows drive ?

Comment: Sorry, posted wrong answer! My answer actually refers to how to reinstall grub and fix grub error!

Comment: I have fixed my answer!